# Can I use just Drupal's commenting section for another Java application?

Tags: drupal-7

We are developing a java based web application. This application needs a commenting functionality. The commercially available commenting services (http://aboutecho.com/ or http://www.livefyre.com/ etc) are not inside my budget. Can I use Drupal's commenting functionality with my Java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am afraid there are no out of the box solutions in drupal that am aware of.

But its is totally possible to use drupal to power your java application's comments.  Am afraid you would have to do some custom coding to make it happen.

Install [drupal 7](http://drupal.org) and a contrib module called [services](http://drupal.org/project/services). By installing services you can extend drupal's resource as services resource. I recommend enabling a REST server (a sub module for services) and using it to communicate with drupal.